# SQL Query Optimization: is SELECT * FROM Persons really that much slower than SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE City='Sandnes'?

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I have a question as to how much faster the SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE City='Sandnes'
```

is from the query

```
 SELECT * FROM Persons
```

is?

From various sources on the net the consensus is that there is a pickup in performance with a more filtered query, but they never seem to get specific.

I realize the answer depends on how big the database is, so let's say there are three databases, one having a mere 1000 records, the second having 1M records, and the third having 10M records.  Assume the records are just a few bytes large, so these data all fit into the server RAM.

How big a difference in speed, in say percent, am I likely to see?  Even a ballpark guess is helpful.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server but that should not matter.

Comment: Looks like something you should measure yourself.

Comment: If I knew the answer I would not ask the community.  Have *you* ever measured it, or just accept it by faith?

Comment: Did some smoke testing on an address table, 1 million rows; just a plain `SELECT *` takes 21'350 reads and 13'695 ms execution time; `SELECT * WHERE City = ....` gives 1'690 reads and 169ms execution time.

Comment: Thanks marc!  That's why I'm not a real SQL programmer but play one on TV...and asking this question here! :)

Answer (score 2):

My favourite answer: "It All Depends"! 
Consider: you have an index on city and the query optimiser uses it, so you will end up doing a series of lookups from index to table because you are requesting all columns (*). If the index is not very selective (e.g. most records are in a particular "city") then this will be much slower than if the index is selective (e.g. only a small number in selected city) and will likely be slower than a full table scan. So if your statistics are not accurate for any reason then the database could possibly take longer to return the filtered set of records than the whole table. 
The only way to answer your question is for you to benchmark using your data, software, and hardware.

Comment: Very, very interesting Lord Peter--and this is why I ask this question.  Never in 1M years would I have thought this to be true for a READ (for CRUD operations I have read that indexing can slow you down, but not for reads).  BTW, this is from an actual problem and now the proposal is to add a "BETWEEN" clause for a certain column in addition to WHERE--would this perhaps slow down the search more?  If you add more and more conditions?  Also it seems for this data the CITY field is not homogeneous but spread out--so it will help speed up the search, all things equal.